# Basics in chess programming

Tags: programming, computer-chess

I'd like to understand the basics behind chess programming.
Would you please recommend any resource to start from?
I have a good understanding of programming in C/C++ and Java.
Thanks,
Giulio

Answer (score 1):

David N. Levy wrote/compiled several books on computer chess basics.  They're a bit old, but as the basics don't change much, they are usually a good place to start.  Those I remember in particular are

D. N. Levy & M. Newborn: How computers play chess

D. N. Levy: Computer Chess Compendium

[www.bookfinder.com](http://www.bookfinder.com) can be a good place to find out-of-print books.